# Solving Non-Linear Differential Equation with Substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble solving this equation

$y'' + (e^{2y} + 1)(y')^3 = 0$

I did the substitution: $y' = v(y)$, leading to the following equation:

$v'v + (e^{2y} + 1)v^3 = 0$

I see that $v = 0$ is a solution so I divide out, leaving me with:

$v' + (e^{2y} + 1)v^2 = 0$

$v' = - (e^{2y} + 1)v^2$

$dy = - (e^{2y} + 1)v^2 dv$

Is this the right direction to proceed? The integral on the right seems intimidating, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: The last ODE is a **separable** one! So no problem should exist to solve it! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you interchange dependent and independent variables, you get a much nicer
equation:
$$ x''(y) = e^{2y} + 1$$
which can be solved by integrating twice.

Comment: How did you spot that? :)

Answer (score 3):

You're fine as far as: $v' = - (e^{2y} + 1)v^2$

This is $\frac {dv}{dy} = - (e^{2y} + 1)v^2$

Your separation of variables has gone wrong: you should get:

$\int \frac 1 {v^2}{dv} = - \int (e^{2y} + 1) dy$

$- \frac 1 {v} = - \frac 12 e^{2y} -y +c$

$v = \frac 2 {e^{2y} +2y +c}$

Recall  that $v=\frac {dy}{dx}$

$\frac {dy}{dx}= \frac 2 {e^{2y} +2y +c}$

$\int( {e^{2y} +2y +c})dy=\int2dx$

$\frac 12 e^{2y} +y^2+cy+d=2x$

$\frac 14 e^{2y} +\frac 12 y^2+cy+d=x$

Answer (score 2):

To me, the most impressive approach is in Robert Israel's answer.

It is based on the fact (see [here](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emaejc/1a20/1as05.pdf), [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Eajm8/M1M1/m1m113.pdf) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566507/prove-that-d2x-dy2-equals-d2y-dx2dy-dx-3)) that $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=-\frac {\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} }{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3}$$ that is to say that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$$ So, the differential equation

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (e^{2y} + 1)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3 = 0$$ just write $$-\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3+ (e^{2y} + 1)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3 = 0$$ Assuming $\frac{dy}{dx}\neq 0$ (that is to say $y\neq c$ which is a particular solution for the given differential equation), then $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=e^{2y}+1\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{e^{2 y}}{2}+y+c_1\implies x=\frac{e^{2 y}}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2}+c_1y+c_2$$

All credit should be given to Robert Israel.