Closed form for a differential equation with sin
I am currently trying to model some dynamics for a project of mine. But I got following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=a\theta+b\cdot \sin(\theta-c)$$
Where $a,b,c,\theta \in \mathbb{R} $
I know how to solve this numerically and tecnically that is also enough, but it would be really neet to have a closed form solution for this problem.
Does someone know if that exists or could give some reference where I might find some?
(Linearizing is not an option because the angle $\theta$ can be  quite a large number).
Sorry if it is obvious that there is or is not a solution to this. Am still quite new in this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is no closed form even in the case of $a=0$ which is well-studied

Multiplying both sides by $\theta'$ and integrating gives an autonomous, nonlinear-first order equation. Integrating thus gives solutions in the form $t = \int^\theta F(u) ,du$ for some function $F$. In our case it looks just about hopeless to integrate $F$ in any sort of nice form for general $a, b, c$. Even the special case $a = 0$ the function $F$ famously involves an elliptic integral function. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599016/is-the-differential-equation-of-the-pendulum-unsolvable
