# What is the relation between $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

What is the relation between $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ ?
For example $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249253/second-derivative-of-the-inverse-function

Comment: There is really no immediate connection between them.

Comment: @grdgfgr: Yes, it's exactly the same (just in a different notation).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005833/prove-that-fracd2ydx2-equals-fracdydx%C3%97-fracddy-fracdydx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have $$\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} = 1 \tag 1 $$  differentiationg $(1)$ with respect to $x,$ we get 
$$\begin{align} 0 &= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{d }{dx} \left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right) \\
&= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} +\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot\frac{d }{dy} \left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\\
&=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3 \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\end{align}$$